# How does a PUT method look in a Play Framework Controller?

Tags: playframework, ebean, playframework-2.4

Yes maybe a trivial question but I can not figure out what to do in my `updatePerson()` method in my Controller ...

**Route:**

```
PUT     /person/:id                controllers.Application.updatePerson(id: Long)
```

**Application.class (Controller)**

```
public Result updatePerson(Long id) {
    ...
    return ok();
}
```

Play Framework version 2.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code should look something like this:

```
public Result updatePerson(Long id) {
    Person person = Person.find.byId(id);
    person.setName("Marcel");
    person.update();
    return ok();
}
```

Comment: Thank you @cosmolev, that's what I have been looking for. Can I access the new values ("name" for example) using bindFromRequest() or similar?

Comment: If you are using bindFromRequest() the update will look this way: `Person person = Form.form(Person.class).bindFromRequest().get(); person.update(id);`

Answer (score 0):

I quite not sure what you are trying to achieve here. But you can do following

1. You can use Play's DI to inject subsequent layer such as Service/DAO layers into your controller to delegate your request. Read [here](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ScalaDependencyInjection) for Play's Dependency Injection choices.
2. To update a person record in data store you need to ensure that person with same id already exists in the database. I think you should work on save functionality first and then come back to update.